# Code is not adding last defualt value

Tags: c++

Im writing an application for my intro to programming class and the objective is to 
set up a simple program that prompts the user to enter a series of positive integer numbers between 50 and 100 (inclusive) using the keyboard. Your prompt should tell the user to enter a negative number to stop the input process.

As the user enters the numbers, you should keep track of the number of valid entries they have made (those that fall in the allowed range), and add up those numbers entries. You do not need to store more than the single entered number, the count, and the current total you are calculating.

Once the user completes the data entry, produce output similar to this:

```
A total of 5 values were entered.
The sum of those numbers is 127
```

make a program that will have one variable and it will retrieve the users

Here is the code I wrote

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int loop = 1;
int value;
int times = 0;

cout << "Enter a negavtive number to quit" << endl;
cout << "\nPlease Enter Any Number Between 50 - 100" << endl;

while (loop == 1) {      
cin >> value;
times++;
value += value;
  if(value < 0) {
    cout << "You entered " << times - 1 << " numbers" << endl;
    cout << "Total: " << value << endl;
    system("PUASE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }// end if statement
} //end while loop

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output
http://www.flickr.com/photos/62751645@N08/6286454476/

I think it may have something to do with the fact that I am using the int value to do two different tasks.
How might I go about fixing this?

## revision

thanks to all of you for the "fix"
I add a new variable and it works like a charm, but now the math is not adding correctly
http://www.flickr.com/photos/62751645@N08/6286526294/in/photostream

Comment: Any particular reason you're using an int instead of a boolean for your loop? Also, you've misspelled `PAUSE` in your loop.

Comment: By the way, I'm not a C++ dev but there seems to be a lot of hate for system() calls. Reasoning is explained here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/ and it certainly makes sense to me to avoid it if you can help it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems, but the major one is this:

```
cin >> value;
```

This means "overwrite `value` with the number the user inputs", and of course if you do that you will never be able to store a sum inside `value` because it will be overwritten each time with the new number.

Solution: use another variable to keep the running total.

You also have a bug in that you do

```
times++;
value += value; // which as described above will not "stick"
```

*before* checking if `value` is negative. These operations should only be performed when `value` is *not* negative; otherwise, data entry should stop immediately and the negative number should not be taken into account for summing the total.

Answer (score 1):

add a sum variable to hold the sum, you overwrite the input value in every loop iteration.

```
sum += value;
```

Comment: thanks to all of you for the "fix" I add a new variable and it works like a charm, but now the math is not adding correctly http://www.flickr.com/photos/62751645@N08/6286526294/in/photostream

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `value` to do two different tasks.

Have another variable called `sum` and accumulate the total there.

The way you're doing things you are writing over your sum every time the user enters a number:

```
cin >> value; // sum of previous values is overwritten!
```

Also there's another problem in that when the user enters a negative number you add that to the sum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not check whether the values are in range (i.e. between 50 and 100). You can put a condition on the line where you do the addition as below:

```
if (value >= 50 && value <= 100)
sun += value;
```

Also, you can use 'value' to break the loop also.

Comment: thank you very much for the heads up the program is now running correctly. The problem was that I had declared the variable "sum" as an integer when in reality it was a double